# Can I rescue my nerve plant?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, indoors, growth

I have this nerve plant ([Fittonia albivenis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fittonia_albivenis)) I got years ago. It grew pretty nicely for a while but I cut it back a bit and then has been declining ever since. It seemed to be improving though but now it seems to be stagnant. It doesn't seem to be dead since it's green with no yellowing or dead parts of the leaves and the stalks are erect, though the leaves are small and a bit droopy.

Is there any way I can help to restore it to its former glory? Does it need any nutrients? Watering changes? Lighting? Is it just dormant (is that a thing? Am I too late?

I put it in some nice potting soil (Promix) at some point, and the pot it's in has a bunch of pebbles at the bottom I got from a gardening store. I don't think I am over-watering it, only when it looks like it needs it. Sometimes I cover it in a clear plastic bag to help it keep moisture in for a bit and that seemed to help it (except for recently).

[image: bird's eye view of plant] [image: side view of plant]

Here's what it looked like in 2019 (though come to think of it my current plant might be a transplant of a cutting from this one and this one eventually kicked the bucket…):

[image: happy 2019 nerve plant]

Thanks!

Comment: @YosefBaskin seems to me that works as an actual answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change Soil**

The plant appears to be suffering from spent soil. You have nothing to lose from moving the entire plant gently into fresh soil.

**Decry those Pebbles**

Pebbles? They are supposed to maintain air pockets, but do nothing for drainage once soil falls in.

**Ignore Dormancy**

Rainforest plants can slow down in winter, but ["almost none go dormant and stop growing."](https://forums.botanicalgarden.ubc.ca/threads/why-do-growers-of-tropical-rain-forest-plants-water-sparingly.58722/)

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, there could be 1 of the 3 reasons:

1. Because of pruning the plant got stressed and is under a shock. You need to give it some time to get out of the shock.
2. The plants is aged and you can't do anything about it.
3. The plant is in a dormant state and will regrow the foliage when its time will come.

Comment: What kinds of things trigger dormant states in plants?

Comment: Googling reveals that it is common for them to go dormant in the winter. Though since it's indoors I'm still a bit curious as to how it would know that, but it might be a combination of lightning, humidity, and temperature. Guess we'll see in a month or two…